# TargetInvocationException occurred, but I have absolutely no idea why

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception, targetinvocationexception

I'm getting this unhandled exception error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll.
>   Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

This is my code in short. It's a calculator of two TextBoxes which should together become a new answer when the user press +, -, /, x button made in [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string numberInString
    {
        get { return TextDoos.Text; }
        set { TextDoos.Text = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        if(TextDoos.Text == "")
        {
            if(TextDoos2.Text == "")
            {
                RekenFunctie(TextDoos.Text, TextDoos2.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}

public int RekenFunctie(string numberInString, string numberInString)
{
    int antwoord;
    int getal = Convert.ToInt32(numberInString);
    int getal2 = Convert.ToInt32(numberInString2);

    if (Buttons.IsPressed) // This is the + button, there are also -,x,/ buttons.
    {
       antwoord = getal + getal2;
       return antwoord;
    }
}
```

I can't see why it isn't working...

Comment: TargetInvocationException always has an InnerException - you should look at that to find out the original cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the call of [InitializeComponent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.icomponentconnector.initializecomponent.aspx) in `MainWindow` constructor;

```
public MainWindow() 
{ 
     InitializeComponent();
     button1.Click += button1_click; //'+' button
}

private void button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int antwoord;
    int getal = Convert.ToInt32(TextDoos.Text);
    int getal2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextDoos2.Text);

    antwoord = getal + getal2;
    resultTextBox.Text = antwoord ;
}
```

Anyway your code is strange. `RekenFunctie` makes some calculation, but you call it from the constructor. So, you run this code only once, but I think your user wants to interact with your calculator.

I think you should read something about [Button.Click](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/705/how-to-add-a-button-click-event-handler-in-wpf.aspx) events.

Comment: No, this question and answer could hepl somebody with similar problem.

Comment: But I can't execute RekenFunctie() in an event-based-method like Buttons_Clicked() because it give me another error, that's why i've put it like that... I still don't get all the restrictions/rules of constructors, events and other stuffs of C# yet.

Comment: I've updated my answer with example how to treat with button events.

Comment: Can you explain me why you have added "button1.Click += button1_Click;". I have removed that line to see what the different is..

Comment: You have a + button. I don't know it's name, so a called it button1. Also, I added the Click event handler. So, if user clicks the button the method button1_click will run. In this method I check the text in TextDoos and TextDoos2 (don't forget to check, if they are not digits(see Int32.TyParse method)). After I calculate the sum and write it to TesultTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.

I was getting the same error when setting the text on a TextBlock from a property changed evet for a TextBox.

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainTextBlock.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
```

I think it was being called at runtime *before* the MainTextBlock component was initialized.

In my case, just checking for *null* did the trick.

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainTextBlock != null)
            MainTextBlock.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
```